# ListView not updating after filtering Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to filter a listview. I am able to see that data is filtered but I don't get anything at the screen. Probably it is just a simple thing.

Part of the code:

```
final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            document: nameDocument,
            name: gaName,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          filtermessageBubbles= messageBubbles;
(...)
FloatingSearchBar.builder(
            pinned: true,
            itemCount: filtermessageBubbles.length,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: filtermessageBubbles[index],
              );
            },
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState(() {
                filtermessageBubbles = messageBubbles.where((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())).toList();
                print(filtermessageBubbles.length);
                print(filtermessageBubbles);
              });
            },
```

and when I run it, I am able to see that filteredmessageBubbler.length reduces its number, but I don't see any change in the virtual device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding a key (`UniqueKey()` for example) to `ListTile` and see if it works

Comment: Could you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: `ListTile(
  key:UniqueKey(),
  title: filtermessageBubbles[index],
  );` and see if it works so I post it as an answer

Comment: Nope, nothing happens. Still no updated.

Comment: Have you fixed this error?